# How to add a click event in jslider in php

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use jslider like in this example: http://egorkhmelev.github.com/jslider/, How can we add a click event on it.

Currently if we click on slider then noting is done

Comment: do you want to trigger something when the slider changes ?

Comment: according to the documentation, you can't - you could use jquery ui slider with the start event: http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-start

Comment: currently slider value change on draggable event, What i want it also change on Click event

Comment: In this demo http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range, clicking also updates slider